# Who are the Parenting evangelists and how do we attract them?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Following our [last community self-evaluation](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/503/lets-get-critical-may-2013-site-self-evaluation), we [came together as a community](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/506/community-evaluation-results-what-can-we-do-to-improve) to figure out what we're doing right and where we could do better when it comes to promoting Parenting Stack Exchange. The consensus on what's going right was rather unanimous, as expected:

- There is a [thriving community](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users) behind this site. When people arrive to ask questions about parenting issues that fall within our [realm of expertise](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), they get great answers in a reasonable amount of time.
- Parenting Stack Exchange is chocked full of [very high quality contributions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is:answer%20score:10) that are well maintained and manicured over time.
- [Community self-moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) is working exceptionally well in this community. Simply reading through a few random questions is enough to realize that the people participating here are very friendly and helpful.

In short, everyone involved is doing *exactly what they're supposed to be doing* in order for this site to succeed, and doing an excellent job of working with a very broad topic on on an extremely strict platform. You've shown that Parenting can work on the Stack Exchange engine, we just need more people to find it *along with* the intrinsic value of the high signal to noise Q&A engine that powers it.

What we need are evangelists. Not just [experts](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200/what-experts-do-we-want-to-attract-and-how), but *evangelists*. I'd like to open a discussion to see if we can identify the following things:

1. Who are the evangelists that would find enough value in what we're doing in order to promote us freely? These are probably *not* going to be people with Wikipedia pages, but could be. Mostly, we're looking for dedicated, forward thinking moms and dads followed by many who are likely to appreciate what we have to offer.
2. How do we attract these people? Is there something we could be showing them that we're not yet doing? Are there places we should be looking that we haven't, or perhaps places where we should be going out of our way to attract attention to the site? Note that contacting someone that you don't know rather well with 'hey, please go look at this' isn't really effective, and is usually considered annoying. If you want to attract an effective evangelist, they'll need to notice your awesomeness.
3. Do you *know* such a person well enough to get in touch with them and show them what we're doing?

Please answer with one idea / person at a time, multiple answers are fine. Within your answer simply describe who, what or where, and any possible caveats involved in the idea. At the end of the discussion, we'll take the ideas the community likes the most and get to work on a solid plan.

Wait, did I forget someone? Are *you* the kind of evangelist that we're looking for? Is there something holding you back? Could we be doing something differently? Please consider leaving an answer to let us know!

Comment: Many programmers are also parents. Right now there are three slots on the right side of the main page of Stack Overflow: one showing the Community Bulletin and two dedicated to Careers. Why not dedicate one of them to promote beta sites like this one? Nice and attractive logo with proper text will surely attract people here and who knows, maybe some will stick. Is there sense in any of this?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of thoughts:

First, WonkoTheSane's post unfortunately devolved into a discussion of one particular question. I have posted three others [previously](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/506/community-evaluation-results-what-can-we-do-to-improve) and I could easily come up with more. When the answers we offer to a particular question all contain "in my opinion" or "in my experience," we are providing advice or a suggestion, not really expertise. Anecdote is fine when the asker is looking for strategies to try, but there is actual research available out there about the consequences of letting children win, the consequences of watching TV at meals, and what toileting behaviors are considered within the range of normal. This [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8125/how-to-deal-with-a-toddler-who-wakes-up-screaming-during-the-night/8170#8170) had 5 people weigh in with their anecdotes before I posted with any research. In this particular case I have real concerns about the child in question; it appears the asker never came back to check answers after receiving the first one or two. So my first thought is that I concur with Wonko that the level of expertise in our answers makes me uncomfortable in evangelizing at this point.

Second, to find evangelists, you might consider:

- An evangelist really believes in what you are doing. And for someone to really believe in what we are doing, he or she has to be an active participant. So what we are asking for is how we might attract people to the site as active members, who *then* might bring followers along.
- We might attract potential evangelists by identifying target groups like meetups, day care centers, mother's day out programs, and parenting bloggers and inviting them to lend their expertise to this community. Let them know we need their expertise (we do!), and let them come and explore. If they like it, they'll stay; if they believe in it, they will share.
- To attract additional experts/evangelists, we have to clearly offer something that people can't get elsewhere. We are competing with other parenting forums, with popular blogs, with ehow and ask.com, with a plethora of parenting magazines and books, and with experts in people's physical communities (doctors' offices, libraries, schools, fellow parents, families, etc). If we can identify ways that we are better than those resources, we might attract people to the cause.

Comment: If you don't object, I'd like to use your last bullet point as a starting point for a new meta discussion: what do we offer that people can't get elsewhere?  Closely related to that discussion might be "what can we offer that we don't already, that might help us distinguish us from the competition?"

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: Hey, I voted this up and think it is a fair assessment we can work on over-all, at the same time, in the end your answer - to go see a professional - **IS** the one that has the top number of votes and that says something too.  I find the quality here to be better than other locations where parents can ask a question and then expect a slew of comments with no moderation, expertise or links at all.

Comment: @balanced mama I think the quality of answers has definitely improved in the last 6 months, but I am not sure there are enough active members to sustain this.

Comment: Well, there are a few more active members now than there were six months ago - I think?!?  It sure seems like it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I put forward this suggestion elsewhere, but the Penny Arcade guys reach a large audience of young parents and touch on [the theme of parenting fairly often](http://www.penny-arcade.com/patv/episode/dvd-deleted-scenes-sample).

As a stepdad, Wil Wheaton discusses family [on his blog all the time](http://wilwheaton.net/2012/11/my-son-is-pretty-funny/).

They have a strong following of diverse and (generally) sensible people, a lot of whom are great contributors to online communities.

Comment: I follow both Penny Arcade and Wil Wheaton.  Honestly, I didn't realize that he was a step-dad.  He's clearly committed to the idea of parenthood to the level where the "step" prefix seems inappropriate.

Comment: It comes up every so often (I think I first read it in "Just A Geek"). I think he's adopted both his kids now, once they were old enough to make the decision themselves.

Comment: Both excellent suggestions. I follow Will in general, but I didn't know this about him - wow. And I mean right there, on his blog ... `50,000 Monkeys at 50,000 Typewriters Can't Be Wrong` - I guess I'm elected to see if he's interested? (see my gravatar that I've had for years if you haven't yet)

Answer (score 0):

Even professionals argue over what is best for kids in certain areas and many studies can be conflicting to various degrees.  This creates a problem for **any** parenting site of this nature and I think SE tends to be far better and have answers of a far higher quality than other sites I have visited.

The unfortunate thing about the format of the site is that answers that are **not** the best answers or babsed on the most current advice or studies can be upvoted and show up at the top of a queue instead of answers that really are of a better quality.  Once in awhile a great point can be made but it might be couched within horrid or judgeemntal assumptions that are off-putting, or bad advice can be given within the context of a perfectly professional sounding answer.

Here is an [example of an answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/5252/2876) that has a generally great message (Preschool isn't all its cracked up to be and no one should feel bad about not sending their child to preschool) that is unfortunately couched with an absolute that makes it sound as if the  idea - (preschools are simply in it for the money only and anyone that sends their child there is just trying to assuage guilt for not being at home) is equally valid.  It is unfortunate, but true, that this "absolutism" is off-putting to some (namely myself and at least Meg Coates who chimes in in the comments with that critique).

There was even [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/6617/2876) in which I was basically asking, is there something I'm missing about the importance of handwriting or am I putting too much importance on typing too soon and I got quite a monitor full from a particular user that has some very specific ideas about the harm of touch-typing (that are contrary to studies I've read), but the user was obviously emotive in his responses and just couldn't let it go (nor would he continue the conversation in chat instead of in comments as he was asked to do multiple times)

My first experience on this site put me at odds with a site member that was vehementally against Homeschooling (having adopted the myth that kids garner socialization skills while at school and that is the only place to obtain them), and no matter what I cited (which, unfortunately, most of my reading has been from books and not sources available online), no matter what I did it was not satisfactory and I was critiqued.  The commenter was voicing a number of popular myths that are out there that many people believe fervently despite studies to the contrary and some of his comments had gotten comment "upvotes" which made me feel very "alone" in the matter.  The whole occurance was extremely off-putting and I almost left the site never to return.  The unfortunate thing is that with our kids, so many things can become emotional like that very quickly and there are a lot of "old fashioned" but still popularly accepted ideas out there as well.

Any user that writes in absolutes, is likely to be off-putting to at least a group of parents - minority or not.  I believe the occurance of these "absolutist" kinds of answers is reduced in the more recent answers (or maybe I just happened upon a lot of it right at the beginning of my involvement here) but, it is the existence of these types of answers and comments that gives me pause about recommending **any** online parenting site as a blanket place to go get good advice.  I have, however, linked or shared specific questions and their answers, and do talk about SE and some of its more recent content with other parents and feel more comfortable recommending the site in this way than I would any other similar site I have been on.

The great thing about SE is that **usually** these emotive absolutes (as well as inaccurate answers) are not voted to the top, flagged and removed when particularly egregious or otherwise commented on and negated in some fashion or another.  I've also seen less of that recently than what I did when I first started visiting the site.  Still, if we can continue to be diligent about removing or editing this kind of content, I think it will give a more professional/ more welcoming face to new visitors **and** old that might choose to, or not to recommend the site if we can continue to whittle away at this type of content.  At the same time, we can't overly edit to where we lose part of the poster's message either so some caution is required, and we will never be rid of **all** such content.  I am glad it is rarely found in top answers.

I think it would help somewhat if there was a clearer way to distinguish actual experts/professionals from people who have experience as parents only (they **are** still experts just of a different kind), but since it is an online and somewhat anonymous presence that is probably impossible.  **Overall, the issue is usually addressed fairly quickly and still better than what happens at most sites.**

Answer (score -5):

I work with hundreds of kids and families, but I cannot send those families here because, quite frankly, the answers are often inaccurate and/or dangerous.

You want to attract people who can send you families, ensure that they won't be burned by their families seeing content which can harm their children.  Most of us who work with families are extremely protective of our kids and highly unlikely to expose them to the possibility of advice which could harm them.

EDIT (reference as requested):
[What should I be teaching my two year old?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5237/what-should-i-be-teaching-my-two-year-old?rq=1)

Top answer, marked as answer.  Lists several developmentally inappropriate skills for a 24 month old.

Comment: Would you care to expound upon this?  Give some examples of answers you have found that were inaccurate/dangerous.  I have found this very rarely, and when answers do seem to smack of inaccuracy, members of the community are quick to jump on the discussion to correct it.

Comment: -1 Claims need to be supported with references. You need to show which answers are "dangerous".

Comment: I edited the post and added a reference to an answer voted up to top as well as marked as answer which lists several skills to teach a 24 month old which are developmentally inappropriate.

Comment: Which of those skills do you feel were developmentally inappropriate? Most of the ones in that top answer are ones our pediatrician asked about at the 24 month checkup, and my 2 year old son does all but coloring within the lines.

Comment: Specifically, please expand upon what advice you believe is actively harmful (harmful vs inappropriate is a major and important distinction).

Comment: Expecting developmentally inappropriate skills from a child is harmful because it increases demands beyond capacities.  Categorizing different colors, numeracy concepts of "how many", coloring within the lines, and shape discrimination are all skills closer to 36 month level than the 24 month level.  Either way I've responded to the question asked with my answer, you can vote me down all you want but the answer remains true.  I don't see a need to respond further, I don't think it would be productive.

Comment: I think there's a gross distinction between an answer you find inappropriate and something that's "dangerous".  I would hardly term the answer to the question you linked to as "dangerous".  FWIW, there is nothing listed in that answer that couldn't fall into the CDC guidelines child development for a 24-month-old.  Just because YOU think they're developmentally inappropriate doesn't mean that they are, in fact, developmentally inappropriate.  Though I would agree that asking a 24 month old to color inside the lines is asking a bit much.

Comment: Downvotes in meta simply indicate disagreement. In this case, I disagree because you make broad claims of widespread "dangerous", advice, yet your sole example not only seems accurate, but is also backed by several expert (read: *professional* child care specialists) users.

Comment: My daughter has been in a Montessori school since prep (or what they call 'casa'), now in second grade. While I found it to be accelerated compared with the K-12 I knew, I didn't find any of the activities or lessons to be age inappropriate. However, thank you for your candid feedback - all insights are extremely important in the scope of tuning our promotional efforts.

Comment: I think this does show something that is an issue within the site. Parenting is such an emotive topic that fairly minor disagreements about development levels get promoted to "dangerous". I know we occasionally lose users because they either feel like their views aren't being represented or are in the minority. Which is inevitable, but Wonko's a clear case of this.

Comment: TO clarify, I'm basing my developmental expectations on normed data from the BDI, DAYC, and E-LAP, as well as Maryland Healthy Beginnings (joint venture between Maryland State Dept. of Ed. and Johns Hopkins University School of Ed.).  These are not my opinions, this is all information from either standardized tests or studies published in peer reviewed journals.  To say that it's not dangerous to apply demands to children which exceed their capacities is to grossly underestimate the impact of communicative stress on a child.  Deep and lasting damage can be done. (character limit or I'd go on)

Comment: Continued..  I've worked with many children over the years who have developed a variety of language and personal/social disorders due to having too much communicative stress placed on them.  The feelings and attitudes formed become the etiology for a variety of disorders ranging from selective mutism to involuntary motor stereotypies.  @Beofett with 10 years of clinical experience and a graduate degree in the field I'd consider myself a professional as well, though I feel that has no bearing on whether one is right, and should give no greater weight to my (or anyone's) words.

Comment: @WonkoTheSane I think part of the confusion is that you seem to be saying that expecting a 2-year-old to be able to do all of the things outlined in that answer (the first list of 7) puts harmful pressure on the child. However, *the answer doesn't seem to be saying "you should expect a 2-year-old to do these things"*. The question is about what skills should a parent work on between 24 and 36 months, and not what skills should a child *already have* at 24 months. Note that the answer takes from Montessori school "expectations", and my understanding is that 24 months is too young for them.

Comment: Cont. To quote you, the skills listed in the answer "are all skills closer to 36 month level than the 24 month level", which does not seem to be in any way at odds with what is presented in the context of either the question or the answer.

Comment: The question said "My two year old..." This leads me to believe the questioner wants to know information about her two year old, not her 35 month child.  1 year is 1/2 of a 24 month child's life, and that year results in a vastly different neural anatomy and physiology, along with vastly different capacity for skills.  When I said closer to 36 months I was trying to be kind and generous, many of those skills are over the 36 month level.  Discriminating several colors (*not* matching), coloring in the lines, shape discrimination (*not* matching).  Expecting a child to perform feats...

Comment: ...he is not ready for neurologically is akin to expecting you to fly.  It's frustrating and just sets you up to feel inadequate and badly about yourself.  This leads to an attitude of "I'm not good at..." which decreases interest in even trying.  This is a typical scenario for many children referred to me who just grunt and point or refuse any communicative acts (because they feel they are bad talkers).  It's not their parents fault, and it's not the fault of well-meaning people here who give advice, but it *absolutely is* why I, as one of the potential "evangelists"...

Comment: ...cannot feel comfortable sending my families to this site as it stands.  With reasonable curation of answers and an open mind to the honest opinions of those people this post is specifically stating it wants to attract, hopefully that can change.  I honestly don't know why it's so hard to understand that the OP asked a question of people like me (there are over 2800 kids in the program I work in, I interact with around 100 of the families) who are in a position to refer, and I answered as to what makes me uncomfortable doing so currently.

Comment: @WonkoTheSane I get it about expecting a child to perform things they aren't developmentally ready for, I really do. Its not a matter of it being "difficult" for me to understand what your concern is.  I just am not seeing *anywhere* in the question or answer that "what should I be *teaching* my 2 year old" is something that can be realistically interpreted "what should I expect my 2 year old to be doing *right now*". Its unfortunate that you feel the site is not one you can recommend, but it really appears that this is based at least in part on you missing the context of the question.

Comment: Setting that aside, you have talked here and other places about "reasonable curation".  Do you have any suggestions as to how that might work?  Your answer seems to be focused on why you think we *won't* be attracting the target audience.  While that's certainly helpful feedback, some suggestions as to the direction you feel we should be going in would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think I'm missing the context of the question, nor the answer.  The response stated that "These are the things that the Montessori school our son attends looks for:" and listed those skills.  Part of teaching involves requesting responses which show comprehension of the subject matter.  Essentially, when one teaches a skill they are requiring performance of that skill in order to affirm that the skill has been acquired.  We teach the age appropriate skills because they are the skills we're neurologically capable of acquiring.  The skills listed were explicit, not general categories.

Comment: If they were general categories (pre-literacy, pre-numeracy, receptive language, expressive language, cognitive skills, etc.) I would think "Oh, they're individualizing the education based on categories of skills."  When one lists specific skills then I expect that they mean the specific skills they list.  As to curation, I wish I had an answer as to how to do it freely and easily.  I think it's going to take a lot of work of first identifying the people you have who DO give good answers (and many do) and then making sure that votes are weighted to try to enhance the strength of those answers.

Comment: I saw one answer wherein the respondent stated that daycares offer extensive and age inappropriate curriculum to appease parent guilt.  That respondent is right, daycares are a business and many of them do work on skills which are not appropriate because they have to cater to their clientele.  That's not to say that daycares are bad, it's just what some need to do.  That answer was voted down significantly and all the comments were quite negative.  I don't know how to find the question, or I'd reference it.  It was a valid and reasonable response to the question and one parents should see.

Comment: If all we listen to is our cheering section then we'll never hear the coach and see what we need to improve.

Comment: I just want to tack on a quick statement about this: " I just am not seeing anywhere in the question or answer that "what should I be teaching my 2 year old" is something that can be realistically interpreted "what should I expect my 2 year old to be doing right now"."  That's exactly what teaching is.  That's like having someone ask the question "What should I teach my 6th grader" and the answer being "neuro-anatomy...   But I don't mean *right now*."  Teaching is an immediate action, not something we expect to see a result from 50% of their life later.

Comment: I guess we just have different definitions of "teaching" then. I don't teach anything predicated on  "okay, show me you know how to do this".  The example of neuronanatomy for a sixth grader is a straw horse. At least some of the skills listed in the answer are clearly ones *some* 24 month olds can do (the op specified her child already could do some). I think we're dealing with such fundamental differences in definitions and perspectives we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Incidentally, I believe the answer you referred to, which commented on how day care curriculum is designed to assuage guilt, is below the answer we're discussing in the same question.  It's also the only answer to that question I upvoted.  I don't think the Montessori based answer is good.  I just don't think its nearly as bad as you do.

Comment: @Beofett Some thirteen year olds go to college, that doesn't mean it's appropriate to recommend that any generic 13 year old should be taught college level material.  I'm not sure how you define teaching if you don't involve the student showing their comprehension and acquisition of the taught skill.   All educational systems I know of use assessment of skills in some way.  Often they tell kids "Now color the rooster red" and see if it happens, if it doesn't the child is encouraged to retry.  If it's an inappropriate skill level the child will eventually become frustrated and may shut down.

Comment: To be more specific: "At least some of the skills listed in the answer are clearly ones some 24 month olds can do (the op specified her child already could do some)."  This is exactly how this becomes dangerous when uninformed answers are given.  To say it's ok to recommend skill levels above the age of the child because in *some* areas the child is advanced sets the child up for failure because each of the skill areas needs to be assessed and the education individualized for that child.  Each child needs their immediate foundational skills worked on, with respect given to whether...

Comment: that specific skill is advanced.  We don't say "Your child has a receptive language score of approximately 28 months, so lets design a curriculum to teach 29 month appropriate cognitive skills."  No, we assess all skill areas and teach foundational skills individualized to the needs of the child.

Comment: Your interpretation of both the context and content of the discussion seems so very far from mine.  You seem intent on defining education as something that occurs at a single point of time, while I see it as a process that occurs over a span of time. You also seem to be saying that all advice is only "safe" if it addresses the most basic milestones (i.e. advice for what a 2 year old should be learning should only include skills all 2 year old should have already mastered). If you'd like to discuss this further, we can take it to chat, but we need to take this out of comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9252/discussion-between-beofett-and-wonkothesane)

Comment: I would encourage you to edit your answer to incorporate some of the clarification you offered here in comments.  In particular, please add in your suggestions about a need to weight the votes in favor of those that you feel would be qualified.

Comment: I think a key issue has been identified here - folks may be somewhat reluctant to send folks here with a sort of "Well, some of the answers there are good, but look out for the dangerous ones" envelope. I think all involved see the expectation that one would apply their own discretion, common sense and wisdom when evaluating responses they see here, but when it comes to _kids_ people tend to be exceptionally careful. This is definitely one to think about, though I'm not sure what we can do. I do think we do a _far_ better job of vetting and reviewing than similar sites however.